# QTreeWidgetItem: get unselected items

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I want to get all not selected items from QTreeWidget.

I have worked on getting selected items, but i want to use not selected items as well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no method to get all items as a single list, you'll have to traverse the tree manually, starting with the topLevelItem()s.

Comment: Currently, i get all selected items, and then get parent of first selected item, and that way, i have access to all of the children,but how do i know which one is not selected?

Comment: QTreeWidgetItem has a method isSelected()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *QTreeWidgetItemIterator* for iterate over the items.
Details and example of using: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html

Inside the loop, you can choose your actions, depending on the property isSelected

```
(*it)->isSelected()
```